# Convert link from node/nid to Pathauto url?

Tags: navigation, path-aliases

Im using Pathauto to make my URLs nice and I may want to change the paths in the future. On some pages Im manually lining to other nodes.

The issue is that if I code the nice URL then the link will be broken if I change the Pathauto settings in the future. If I link to node/(the node id) then the link will always work, but its bad for SEO to not have keywords in the anchor text.

Is there a way to code in the NID so it always works but on the page show the nice URL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would, as Splat mentioned, check out the Global Redirect module, which will help out with google not seeing node/FOO and pretty/path pointing to identical content.  If, however you are wanting to make sure that when engines scan your page content and pretty/path shows up inside the HTML, you can either continue to hardcode the paths, or create a function that returns the aliased path based on the nid.

```
function make_my_path($nid) {
  $pretty_path=drupal_get_path_alias('node/' . $nid);
  return $pretty_path;
}
```

Then use that (or `drupal_get_path_alias()` directly) in your templates or preprocess functions, or just use [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/6).  If it is passed 'node/FOO' as the path, it will return the aliased path if one is set. (Unless you explicitly tell it not to; see [`url()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/url/6).)

So, for example, `print l('Hello World','node/23');` should return `<a href="/pretty/path/to/node/23">Hello World</a>`.

Comment: Thanks. Shame their isn't a module to remove the need for so much code.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using CKEditor, you should use the [CKEditor Link](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link) module. It allows searching content by title to insert, and in Drupal it saves the link as /node/[ID]. Then a text filter (which you'll need to enable for each text format it's being used on) replaces that URL with the current path alias in the rendered page.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module. This will make sure whenever you link to node/*x* that anyone following the link is redirected to the clean URL for that node.

Comment: No, I want it so on the page with the link the actual html isn't node/x but instead it's the nice Pathauto URL. Users will never notice the difference, but search engines do. Thanks