# Should I rewrite my links into aliases?

Tags: path-aliases

Is it of any advantage, in addition to using Global Redirect, to rewrite html links from `/node/nid` to `/article/this-is-the-title`, even though in both cases traffic is directed to `/article/this-is-the-title` (by Global Redirect).

## Edit:

From [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/23977/10520) I gather that I should use [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) so that aliases wouldn't cause "duplicate" content.

The same [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/23977/10520) suggests a way to intercept links, passing them through functions to "convert from node/nid to article/title". However, I am green at coding Drupal, and have no clue as to go about it. Could some one advise on alternatives? Or ways of making this less cumbersome?

I am also adding [this link to a related answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29625/10520) on avoiding disadvantages of 'same content/multiple URLs' for whoever's reference.

Comment: Pathauto does not do redirecting. It is just meant to automatically generate URL/path aliases for various kinds of content.

Comment: So if you use Pathauto, the links will not change? If so, how do you use generated aliases?

Comment: No. They'll just have an _alias_. For e.g. if you have a page and its path is `<yoursite_url>/node/1`, pathauto will create an alias using the `title` of the content type. If the page title is `foo bar` then the alias will most probably be `<yoursite_url>/content/foo-bar`. Note that the page will also be accessible via `<yoursite_url>/node/1`. Nodes will have alias but the redirection to that alias is not handled by Pathauto.

Comment: How do you change the links into SEO friendly links? As I understand that is key for SEO, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: The edit you made is actually the solution for your queries. Global Redirect and Pathauto is a winning combination. Also, for SEO see the [SEO Checklist](http://drupal.org/project/seo_checklist) module

Comment: What I am still unsure of is if it is of any advantage to convert links in content into their aliases SEO-wise?

Comment: This is a SEO question rather than Drupal. On that note, wouldn't it be easier (for Google bots) and also make sense to search for `<yoursite_url>/what-is-search-engine-optimisation` rather than `<yoursite_url>/node/1`? (as an example)

Comment: I may have expressed myself in an unclear manner. I will rewrite my question.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/23977/10520) I gather that I should use [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) so that aliases wouldn't cause "duplicate" content.

The same [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/23977/10520) suggests using the l() function to have Drupal use "pretty paths" automatically.

I am also adding [this link to a related answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29625/10520) on avoiding disadvantages of 'same content/multiple URLs' for whoever's reference.