# How do I prevent accessing a page with /node/37 directly when an alias has been set?

Tags: 8, uri

I work with Drupal 8.

I've set an `url alias` for my page to `/nice-url`.
When I acces it via `http://mypage.com/nice-url` everything works fine.

The problem is, this page is still accessable via `http://mypage.com/node/37` - it's bad for SEO and it produces some mess.

Is it possible to remove that `http://mypage.com/node/37` page? I mean I want the content of that page to accessable **only** via `http://mypage.com/nice-url`.

Comment: I know you are looking for drupal 8. But for drupal 7 this same question-Answer is available, you can check to get idea to apply for your need. [Convert link from node/nid to Pathauto url?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23968/convert-link-from-node-nid-to-pathauto-url)

Comment: _it's bad for SEO_ That's simply not true. Run it through any SEO tool, it will report that canonical meta tags are used properly, as recommended by all major search engines

Comment: @Clive agree about SEO - but still... bots generate twice as much traffic for no reason; secondly: redundancy is never good (for example: I could forget about double way of accessing same page and make some twigs that will affect one of it and not the other etc.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to deny access to it but simply redirect to the aliased URL.

That feature is provided by the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module and there's also a [core issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2641118) to make core do that automatically.

Comment: The core issue you linked to looks promising. I see that it provides solution for`'- path alias redirect, for example from "node/1" to "content/my-node"` which is exactly what I need. But - how to use it/enable it?

Comment: You don't. It's a work in progress patch.  Use the redirect module. As I said, it does the same

Answer (score 0):

You could check the URI:

```
$uri = RequestStack $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

If the URI is 'node/37' you can `throw new AccessDeniedHttpException();`

But I don't think that this will improve your SEO.